# Using regular expressions to remove (complicated?) string patterns

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I tried finding similar questions, and of formulating a solution on my own. However, I am not very satisfied, and so, decided to ask the question here.

**Aim:**
I want to remove some expressions (*"c(\"*, and *\"a\"*) that appear at the start and end of my strings, using `regular expressions` and `gsub`.

```
#test strings 1 and 2
string1<- "c(\"can't remember the last time\" \"\\a\")"
string2<- "c(\"can't remember the last time\" \"a\")"

#Attempted solution for string1
string1<- gsub("^.\\(","",string1)
string1<- gsub("\\\\.","",string1)

#Result
string1
> "\"can't remember the last time\" \"\")"
```

**Question 1:** How can I remove the remaining backslashes withour running into the trailing backslash problem? I cannot use `[[:punct:]]` as that removes other punctuation marks too.

```
#Attempted solution for string2
string2<- gsub("^.\\(","",string2)
string2<- gsub(".\\{1}","",string2)

#Result
string2
> "\"can't remember the last time\" \"a\")"
```

**Question 2:** How can I remove the 'a\' expression and the remaining backslashes?

PS. The strings were acquired as a result of exporting data from a Word document's tables to text files using Java, and then importing the text files into `R`. But I just want to see how `regular expressions` can be used to clean this mess, instead of finding some issue with the Java program that exported the data.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Apologies for not making the question clear. This is how I would like the final sentence to be:

```
"can't remember the last time"
```

**2nd-EDIT**

The story of the strange string: The strings shown above were selected from a corpus, which I built using the `tm` package, with the `DirSource` command. The original text was saved in MS Word, in tabular form. I exported it using Java to create text files for each string, and the imported them to R.
The dput, if it helps, is as follows

```
structure(c("Can't remember the last time", 
"\a"), Author = character(0), DateTimeStamp = structure(list(
    sec = 40.6046140193939, min = 56L, hour = 13L, mday = 29L, 
    mon = 5L, year = 113L, wday = 6L, yday = 179L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Description = character(0), Heading = character(0), ID = "comment1.txt", Language = "english", LocalMetaData = list(), Origin = character(0), class = c("PlainTextDocument", 
"TextDocument", "character")) 
"\a"), Author = character(0), DateTimeStamp = structure(list(
    sec = 40.7186260223389, min = 56L, hour = 13L, mday = 29L, 
    mon = 5L, year = 113L, wday = 6L, yday = 179L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Description = character(0), Heading = character(0), ID = "comment99.txt", Language = "english", LocalMetaData = list(), Origin = character(0), class = c("PlainTextDocument", 
"TextDocument", "character"))
```

I can see the "c(" and "\a" in the code above.

Comment: Perhaps post the exact result(s) that you want.  Maybe it is clear to others, but I am not sure what the desired result is.

Comment: The expression `\"a\"` doesn't appear at the end of `string1`. Is the stuff at the end of a string fixed, or varying?

Comment: I'm also guessing you don't really want the double quotes to remain in the string....

Comment: @MarkMiller Apologies. I have edited to show the desired appearance of the sentence.

Comment: @HongOoi Yes. In detail, there are two types of strings I am having to deal with. The first type contains "c(\" at the beginning and "\\a\)" at the end, as shown in string 1. This pattern remains fixed for all strings of type 1.
Likewise, for string type 2, all strings begin with "c(\" and end with "\a\)".
So, the stuff at the end of both types of string is fixed.

Comment: What I mean is, you show two ending substrings: `" "a"` and `" "\a"`. So both of these substrings can occur. Got it.

Comment: @HongOoi ^ Yes, that's correct. And it is OK if the double quotes are removed from the string.

Comment: How did you get these strings in the first place?  They look like R code.  There might be a better way to approach this if you give more background.

Comment: I had intended to add the dput of my corpus, from which I selected the two strings above. But I feared the length of the post may put off readers here. I will add the dput and the package used to construct the corpus. Just to restate, I exported the text from MS Word docs into text files, and then imported into R.

Comment: Ugh. Your data looks fine, you're just confused. You also seem to have skipped a line in your `dput`.

Comment: I left out dput(myCorpus[[1]]). Comparing with examples of other users' dput elsewhere, I don't think I left out anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two substrings at the start and the end are fixed for all strings, you don't need regexes at all. Just use `substr`:

```
substr(string2, 4, nchar(string2) - 6)
```

If the substring at the end is variable, but can only contain backslashes, double quotes and `a`, the regex is:

```
"[\\\\ \"a]*)$"
```

Thus we can use `sub` as follows:

```
sub("[\\\\ \"a]*)$", "", substr(string1, 4, nchar(string1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing two different ways of addressing the problem. I am just digesting the substr function, which I hadn't used before.

Just a question regarding the regex, if I may: the character class is doing 'fixed matching' on the string, isn't it? So that we can't add, for example ^ in [^\\\\ \"a] to show that \\ appear at the start?
Or am I terribly misled?

Answer (score 2):

As @Mark Miller points out, your question is not very clear. But I guess that

```
library( stringr )
str_replace_all( string1, '\\"', "" )
```

solves your first problem and then

```
string2 <- str_replace_all( string2, '\\"a', "" )
str_replace_all( string2, '\\"', "" )
str_replace( str2, ')', "" )
```

the second.

Comment: This does the job. Thanks. I had forgotten to try str_extract_all, thinking that I am using the same function (gsub) that underlies this anyway.

But I will be thankful to view any other answers/approaches from other users.

Comment: Confused; how does this get rid of the `c(` at the start of the string?

Comment: @HongOoi Actually, this code adds to my solution. So, I already get rid of the "c(" using my code, and use the aforementioned to clean up the remaining mess.